# Select from two tables statement

Tags: database, vb.net, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have two tables

```
+------------------------------------+
| Family                             |
|------------------------------------|
| FamilyID                           |
| Family Tel                         |
| Address                            |
| Area                               |
+------------------------------------+

+------------------------------------+
| Members                            |
|------------------------------------|
| Family ID                          |
| Person Name                        |
| Person Tel                         | 
| Person Job                         |
| Birthday                           |
+------------------------------------+
```

I want to make a search in table `members` in column `Person Name`, but I want it to return all the members in the table who have the same `Family ID` and also to return from the table `Family` the family data for the same ID although the search will be by the person name

Any clue?

Comment: What have you tried and what specific problem are you having.  SO isn't a free code writing service, you're expected to put in some effort.

Comment: This request has some logical problems. What if two persons have the same name but belong to different families? Or "Person Name" contains both the name and the Surname? (And in any case, this will not rule out homonimy)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because there is only one family and many members, it is probably best to do two queries instead of one (with one query, each member will have its own copy of the family info).

```
SELECT Family.* from Family INNER JOIN Members ON Members.FamilyID = Family.Family
WHERE Member.PersonName = "Joe"

SELECT B.* from Members A INNER JOIN Members B ON A.FamilyID = B.FamilyID
WHERE A.PersonName = "Joe"
```

If you really wanted a single query:

```
SELECT B.*, Family.* FROM Members A INNER JOIN Members B ON A.FamilyID = B.FamilyID, Family
WHERE A.PersonName = "Joe"
AND Family.FamilyID = B.FamilyID
```

Comment: and how to use the two queries to get in the code to get one family and all of it's members??

Comment: If you're asking how to read an access database from VB.NET (based on your tags), then I suggest you Google it.  Here's one example: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11384216/database-access-in-vb-net).

Comment: I was actually wondering about how to union them but I did it already ..thx a lot for your help

Answer (score 0):

the trick is to join the members table twice once for filtering a porson by name and once to display all familiy memebers
try something along the lines of this:

```
    SELECT members.*, family.adress
    FROM members AS members_1 INNER JOIN (members INNER JOIN family ON     members.familyId=family.FamilyId) ON members_1.familyId = members.familyId
    WHERE (((members_1.name)="john"));
```